# ajaxSend bind and then 2 async $.get requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a simple page, with binding ajaxSend event. When it fires a new class "ajax-loading" appends to a specific element. And second bind is for ajaxComplete, when it fires, a class "ajax-loading" removes from element. 
And the problem is, when i have two asynchronous ajax requests.

They starts fast and seems like immediately, but when first ajaxComplete fired, a class "ajax-loading" is removed. although second ajax is not yet completed.

How can i keep "ajax-loading" until second ajaxComplete fired ? 
The code is simple:

```
    $('h1').bind('ajaxSend', function() {
        $(this).addClass('ajax-loading');
    }).bind('ajaxComplete', function() {
        $(this).removeClass('ajax-loading');
    });
    $('h1').click(function() {
        $.get('');
        $.get('');
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement a counter. Instead of using a JavaScript variable, you can also attach it to the element, using [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/).

```
var ajaxRequests = 0;
$('h1').bind('ajaxSend', function() {
    ajaxRequests++; //Increase counter
    $(this).addClass('ajax-loading');
}).bind('ajaxComplete', function() {
    if (--ajaxRequests == 0) { // Decrease counter by one, and check for zero
        $(this).removeClass('ajax-loading');
    }
});
$('h1').click(function() {
    $.get('');
    $.get('');
});
```

Comment: @RusAlex If the requests don't have to be fired simultaneously, it's the best solution. If the requests are always fired with each other, pimvdb's solution is also a decent choice.

Comment: I think you should check for `2` instead.

Comment: @pimvdb No, that would break the code for the next time. I have just ninja-edited my answer, and added `--` (`--ajaxRequests`) to get it work all the time. Note that it doesn't matter how many AJAX requests are fired, as long as they're completed, the loader is removed.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using `Deferred`:

```
$('h1').addClass('ajax-loading');

$.when($.get(''), $.get(''))
 .then(function() {
     $('h1').removeClass('ajax-loading');
 });
```

It will only remove it when both are completed.